# How to remove negative values from a List<int>?

Tags: c#, algorithm, generics, arraylist

I'm ending up with a bunch of ints in my List (named "listInts").

That should not surprise anybody.

My problem is I don't want any negative numbers in there, but there is the possibility of having three, specifically -1, -2, and -3.

I can clumsily remove them via:

```
if (listInts.Contains(-1) {
    int i = listInts.IndexOf(-1);
    listInts.Remove(i);
    // etc.
}
```

...but I know this exhudes a code smell stenchier than a whole passle of polecats.

What is a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use LINQ:

```
listInts = listInts.Where(i => i >= 0).ToList();
```

Depending on how this is going to be used, you could also avoid the `ToList()` call and not resave the values:

```
var positiveInts = listInts.Where(i => i >= 0);
```

This will still let you enumerate as needed.

If you need to change the list in place, [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) is actually a more efficient method:

```
listInts.RemoveAll(i => i < 0);
```

However, I do not prefer this as it's a method that causes side effects, and tends to be confusing (hence hampering maintenance) if you're using other LINQ extension methods.

Comment: Though .RemoveAll will be better since it is implemented as a list method, and will perform the operation on the list itself, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I edited to mention that, including why I prefer this over RemoveAll

Comment: It confuses the ones that don't know. I would expect coders to know coding before trying to maintain one. Efficiency + Commenting = Win.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I actually prefer my second option - which is often more efficient than either.  Side effects in maintainability, though, also include locking you into `List<T>` for your original implementation.  If, later, you change collections, `RemoveAll` will all of a sudden become a compiler error... Using LINQ allows you more flexibility.  (I'd also never commend a RemoveAll method ;) )

Comment: I agree that in general working with IEnumerable<T> is a smart choice, but still, if the I already have the variable as a list, I would use the RemoveAll method.

Answer (score 9):

```
listInts.RemoveAll(t => t < 0)
```